# How to remove '-' and trim white space of map's key using Java Stream API

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a map

```
Map<Object, Map<String, Object>> salesReportForSoldPropertyMap= salesReportForSoldProperty.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(tags -> tags.get("E"), Function.identity()));
```

When I am converting Map to JSON, I am getting this

```html
  {
  "Sold Promissory Buyer": 
    {
      "A": 2616100,
      "B": 2616100,
      "C": 31,
      "D": "Sold Promissory Buyer"
    },
  "Auction": 
    {
      "A": 101322143.24,
      "B": 50243301.2,
      "C": 569,
      "D": "Auction"
    },
  "Sold Third Party":
    {
      "A": 72000,
      "B": 93900,
      "C": 1,
      "D": "Sold Third Party"
    }      
}
```

But here I have a problem, I don't want white spaces and '-' in JSON key. So Can we solve it by JAVA Stream API, so it will give me map's key without white spaces and '-'? like key "Sold Third Party" should be "SoldThirdParty"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may transform keys having values unchanged via `toMap` collector:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> result = input.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString().replaceAll("[- ]", ""),
                              e -> e.getValue()));
```

Note that your original keys are objects to you need to convert them to strings either via cast (`(String)e.getKey()`), or calling `toString()`.

Note that after applying the replacement different keys might become the same. For example, if your original map contained `"A-B"` and `"AB"` keys, both will be converted to `"AB"`. In this case `Collectors.toMap` will throw `IllegalStateException`. To handle such case specially you may specify the merge function as the third `toMap` parameter.

Comment: Good answer, but there is a caveat: This code will explode if after removing dashes and spaces two keys are the same.

Comment: btw, you can use a shorter regex `" |-"` (instead of `"[- ]"`

Comment: @Bohemian, this is covered by [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35180143/4856258) asked by OP. Nevertheless edited the post to warn future readers. Thanks.

Comment: Future visitors are not psychic. Better to comment here so this Q+A is complete by itself.