# How to add inner elements of Map when keys are duplicate with Java Stream API

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a List of `List<Map<String, Object>>` like this

```html
[
   {"A": 50,
      "B": 100,
      "C": 200,
      "D": "Auction"
    },
    {
      "A": 101322143.24,
      "B": 50243301.2,
      "C": 569,
      "D": "Sold Promissory Buyer"
    },
    {
      "A": 500,
      "B": 1000,
      "C": 1500,
      "D": "Auction"
    }]
```

I am using this stream API method to convert this list into Map

```
finalSalesReportForSoldProperty.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(tags -> ((String) tags.get("D")).replaceAll("[\\- ]", ""), Function.identity()));
```

But it throws me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key` exception, because my list has duplicate keys

I want to add the inner elements of duplicate key, I want my output like this

```html
    "Auction": {
           "A": 550, 
           "B": 1100, 
           "C": 1650, 
           "D": "Auction" 
      } ,
"Sold Promissory Buyer" :{ 
          "A": 101322143.24,
          "B": 50243301.2,
          "C": 569,
          "D": "Sold Promissory Buyer"
        }
```

Is it possible through Java stream API?

Comment: The type of the value is `Object`. How do you define addition on that? Or can we assume it is `Double`?

Comment: @Tunaki type of value is Object so I am putting only String and Double value. I want to make the value of "D" as key and rest elements should be added for the duplicate values.

Comment: Yes we can assume it as a Double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `mergeFunction` parameter of the [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector. This function is called on duplicate values and will merge those two values into a new one.

In this case, we need to merge two maps by summing the values with the same key. The easiest solution to do that is to iterate over all the entries of the second map and merge each entry in the first map. If the mapping does not exist, it will be created with the correct value. If it does, the new value will be the sum of the two current values.

Now, assuming each value is in fact a `Double`:

```
finalSalesReportForSoldProperty.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    tags -> ((String) tags.get("assetStatus")).replaceAll("[\\- ]", ""),
    Function.identity(),
    (m1, m2) -> {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(m1);
        m2.entrySet().stream()
                     .filter(e -> e.getValue() instanceof Double)
                     .forEach(e -> map.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (o1, o2) -> ((Double) o1) + ((Double) o2)));
        return map;
    }
));
```

Comment: Will it add all the elements.? I don't want to add value of "D", because this is String and want the same value. Can we put any condition to avoid it using filters or something?

Comment: @SonuGupta Yes, you can add a filter to filter only the double values. I edited.

Comment: There is some problem, Values are not getting added.

Comment: @SonuGupta Then this is because your values aren't `Double` :) Mapping should be `"A": 50.0,` to have a double value. I'm guessing there is a mix of integer and double.

Comment: Ok @Tunki I will take care of it. Thank you so much.